# How to batch-change same characters in notepad++ column

Tags: notepad++, regex

I some MCQ questions
and I need to change the answers start from

```
(A) answer  
(B) answer   
(C) answer   
(D) answer   
(E) answer
```

TO

```
A) answer    
B) answer   
C) answer   
D) answer   
E) answer
```

There is another problem, is there some questions comes only with 3 answers like a, b and c
and some comes with 4 answers .. even some with only 2 answers as just A) and B).

Is there a way to make the changes and maintain the questions and the answers intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only remove open parenthesis at the beginning, not inside the answers.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*\K\(`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\(          # open parenthesis, have to be escaped as it has special meaning in regex
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open find and replace with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

In `Find what:` enter `(`

Keep `Replace with:` empty

Click `Replace all`

As long as there is no other occurence of `(` this will work, if there is, you need to provide at least a text example.